# How to make an item in a list view non clickable in Android

Tags: android, listview

How to make the items in a list view not click able. i got topics and items in a list view but the view is same for both topics and items. the items are click able but the topic is not click able. how to achieve this

the list will look like

```
Topic
item
Topic
item
item
```

topic. click able(false) did not work, please help

Comment: Have you tryed expandable listviews ??

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Sharing my experience, the following did the trick (view refers to the list item view):

```
view.setEnabled(false);
view.setOnClickListener(null);
```

- enabling by overriding the method didn't work as the method was never invoked.
- setting focusable to false didn't work as well.

Comment: The problem with my solution is re-enabling the click. One you nullified the click listener, you don't know what was the listener that the ListView previously used. See the isEnabled solution if you may want to re-enable the click/selection option: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#isEnabled(int)

Comment: Mine is crashing on 'setOnClickListener'

Answer (score 72):

Don't know if you still need it, but you can implement your own Adapter and override the method isEnabled(int position). Depending on the ViewType of the item you will return true or false.

Comment: enabling by overriding the method didn't work as the method was never invoked

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka can you explain what didn't work? For me it worked perfectly and I think is the most elegant solution.

Comment: This method prevented the separator lines from showing in between my list items. Instead, I set the following property in the XML of the ListView `android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"` and it worked for me.

Answer (score 19):

To make the items in a list non-clickable, you have to make the adapter return false on its `isEnabled` method for the items in the list. An easy way to instantiate an adapter and override `isEnabled` can be done in the following way:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null, from, to, 0) {
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: This method prevented the separator lines from showing in between my list items. Instead, I set the following property in the XML of the ListView `android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"` and it worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

**This is the correct answer:**

I've found a lot of comments saying that

```
setEnabled(false)
setClickable(false)
setFocusable(false)
```

would work, but the answer is **NO**

The only workaround for this approach is doing:

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_storage_divider, parent, false);
view.setOnClickListener(null);
```

Answer (score 5):

Set listSelector transparent in ListView

```
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 1):

In your adapter, you have that put this:

```
view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.items_menu_header, null);    
view.setOnClickListener(null);
```

I use a boolean to identify if header or item, so I assign a different layout for each type.

Answer (score 1):

In your `ListView` add the following attribute

```
android:cacheColorHint = "#00000000"
```