# Skip item View (list item) when data is Null using BaseAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter

> I want to populate my listView with songs. And some songs are not streamable. I want to skip inflating(drawing) those item rows. whose data is null.

I have tried by `setEnable(false)` and `setClickable(false)`. But it isn't the right solution.

**I want to skip those item rows which are not streamable**

```
public View getView(int position , View convertView , ViewGroup parent)
    {
        String track_artWork = "";

        MyViewHolder mViewHolder;

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_listview, parent, false);
            mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
        }
        else
        {
            mViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Track currentTrack = trackList.get(position);

        if(!currentTrack.isStreamable())
        {
            //convertView.setEnabled(false);
            //convertView.setClickable(false);
            //convertView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            return convertView;
        }

        mViewHolder.tvSong.setText(currentTrack.getTitle());

        track_artWork = String.valueOf(currentTrack.getArtworkUrl());

        mViewHolder.smartImageView.setImageUrl(track_artWork);

        return convertView;
    }
```

**Second Approach**

I set the `item_listView` parent **Node visibility to gone in xml**. and I invert the method from ! streamable to isStreamable.

```
    if(currentTrack.isStreamable())
    {
        convertView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

It will work when displayed for first time. As i scroll ListView It displays the item.And on click of it my app crashes.

Comment: Simply do not add those tracks to your tracklist?

Comment: But i wanna show all of them. Whether they are streamable or not. But if they are not streamable show toast onclik of it . That it is not streamable

Comment: Try setOnclickListener(null). Or refer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389997/how-to-set-an-item-in-a-listview-not-clickable-android

Comment: Click is implemented on listView.setOnItemClickListener not in adapter.

Comment: Override `public boolean isEnabled (int position){...}` in the adapter and put your logic (`currentTrack.isStreamable()`) in.